# value in custom Context Provider accessed through custom hook is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and am having trouble with a value defined in a custom context provider. I access the value in a component under the provider with a custom hook but it's reported as being undefined. I've gone through the questions on SO and have verified my syntax with the lesson in my book but can't find the problem.

This is my custom provider and custom hook:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';

const ApiContext = createContext();

export const useApi = () => useContext(ApiContext);

export const ApiProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();
    const [baseImageUrl, setBaseImageUrl] = useState();

    const apiKey = 'api_key=SECRET';

    const baseUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';

    const objToParams = (obj) => {
        let params = '';
        if(obj) {
            const keys = Object.keys(obj);
            for(let key of keys) {
                params += `&${key}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`;
            }
        }
        return params;
    }

    const api = {
        get: async (path, params) => {
            const resp = await fetch(baseUrl + path + '?' + apiKey + objToParams(params));
            return await resp.json();
        }
    }

    useEffect( () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const config = api.get('/configuration');
            console.log(config);
            config.images && setBaseImageUrl(config.images.secure_base_url);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            setError(error);
        }
        finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, []);

    if( loading ) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }
    if( error ) {
        return <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>;
    }
    return (
        <ApiContext.Provider value={{ api, baseImageUrl }}>
            { children }
        </ApiContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

and this is the component where I access the value through the custom hook:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ApiProvider, useApi } from './components/context/ApiProvider';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])
  const [searchError, setSearchError] = useState();

  const {api} = useApi();

  const onSearch = (query) => {
    try {
      setSearching(true);
      setSearchResults(api.get('/search/multi', {query: encodeURIComponent(query)} ));
      console.log(searchResults);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setSearchError(error);
    }
    finally {
      setSearching(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <ApiProvider>
      <div className="main-layout">
        <Header onSearch={ onSearch }/>
        <Main
          searching={ searching }
          searchError={ searchError }
          searchResults={ searchResults }
         />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </ApiProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't consume the context in the component where you apply it.

```
<ComponentA>
  <Context.Provider value={"somethong"} >
    <ComponentB/>
  </Context.Provider>
</ComponentA>
```

In the above example, only ComponentB can consume the value. ComponentA can't.
If you wan't to consume the value in your App component, it has to be the child (or grandchild ...) of the ContextProvider.

```
<Context.Provider value={"somethong"} >
  <App/>
</Context.Provider>
```

If I understand your code correctly than you are trying to consume the context in your App, while also returning the provider for the same context.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!